# Pinescript: var array deep copy help request (reference data types)

Tags: arrays, pine-script, var, pine-script-v5, deep-copy

Having trouble with VAR declarations in pinescript.  arrary.splice is the shallow copy, i have used array.copy instead, however I am still seeing this as a shallow copy.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Var Deep CopyTest")

var float[]a = array.new_float(1, close)
float[]b = array.copy(a) //deepcopy so that b is close
a.shift() //delete element in a
a.push(open)//make a be open

plot(array.sum(a) / 1)//should be open of every bar but is open of prior bar
plot(array.sum(b) / 1)//should be close of every bar
```

Removing the "var" declaration in the above creates a plot of open and close as expected. I know this, am looking for help in how to perform non shallow copies of var types (have other longer code which needs a var and having weird outputs because it appears to be shallow copy).

The current output of the attached code is plot of open and open-1, no idea why or how it is open-1 for b.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.